# Fatal error : execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table which contains 6.5 million records. When I try to access that table from phpMyAdmin I get:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp-new\phpMyAdmin\libraries\display_tbl.lib.php on line 1457.

I am just trying to view the records and I am not doing any query which might cause the error.

This problem is only in my server. And my local machine does not contain as many records as the server.

In my `php.ini` I have already set the maximum execution time to maximum.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add this line

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

to **phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

And Change **php.ini** and **my.ini**

- post_max_size = 750M
- upload_max_filesize = 750M
- max_execution_time = 5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 1000M
- max_allowed_packet = 200M (in my.ini)

Comment: This is the answer that is really helpful. It does not help to edit `max_execution_time` in the ini, PHPMyAdmin has for some obscure reason its own built in maximum set.

Comment: Only adding `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;` in _config.inc.php_ was enough to solve my problem (phpmyadmin 4.4.14).

Answer (score 7):

if you are using xammp on the xammp control panel at the apache line click on config and then click to open PHP(php.ini) find and increase max_execution_time=30 to max_execution_time=600.

Answer (score 6):

+1 for making me lookup *lakhs*. That looks like a PHP timeout to me as the *default timeout is 30 seconds*. Increase the setting in your php.ini and restart apache and see if the timeout persists.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: In the php ini i had already setup the maximum execution time to maximum.But yet the problem persists

Comment: Check this out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin and make sure you are editing the correct file and are restarting the service, and check your *xamp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php* settings

Answer (score 2):

you need to set max_execution_time in php.ini

max_execution_time=6000

HAPPY CODING

Answer (score 1):

This solution has resolved the issue
Place the following lines at the top of the script page and before the query that initiates the memory:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(1800);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

Look for : $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;

change '600' to '6000'.

Answer (score 0):

Open the xampp folder at your computer where it is installed. For example, it is at C: drive into my PC, and then open the phpMyAdmin and then libraries folder.

**"C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries”**

you will find a file there named, "config.default.php". Open the file into any editor or in notepad and find the line "$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;", change the value to 0. i.e. $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; and save the file. After saving the file restart your xampp control panel.
Hurrah! Your problem has been solved.