# How to solve fatal error in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

when i open phpmyadmid that time this error occuers...
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\PMA.php on line 10

how to solve it???

Comment: Check that: [Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin) and [Fatal error : execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833536/fatal-error-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Below link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

please go to 
xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;

And Change php.ini

max_execution_time = 5000