# How can i start the admin panel of mysql in xamp as it is showing a fatal error?

Tags: mysql

As I clicked on the admin panel of `mysql` in, `xampp` I am getting error as:

> Fatal error: macimum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in c:\xampp\phpmyadmin\libraries\errorhandeler.php on line 162

how can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error : execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833536/fatal-error-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Please follow already have solution at stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833536/fatal-error-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

to phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

And Change php.ini and my.ini

- post_max_size = 750M
- upload_max_filesize = 750M
- max_execution_time = 5000
- max_input_time = 5000
- memory_limit = 1000M
- max_allowed_packet = 200M (in my.ini)

Comment: Your loop might be endless. If it is not, you could extend the maximum execution time like this:

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes