# Php Xampp :: Phpmyadmin can not open on local host

Tags: phpmyadmin

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\ErrorHandler.php on line 162

Comment: And what's on line 162 of that file? If you could also include relevant sections of your Apache error log, that might also be helpful.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15833536/209139

Comment: What are you doing when the problem occurs - have you gotten to the dialog to enter your username and password? Does anything display on the next page other than the error message?