# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Language.php on line 18

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833536/fatal-error-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

Increase execution limit in php.ini

max_execution_time= 10000

And restart your server

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833536/fatal-error-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-phpmyadmin