# I installed XAMPP and when clicking My SQL Admin I get this error. I followed all installation processes successfully

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This error comes up in the redirected site.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php on line 192

It should redirect me to a localhost website to create a database.

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894993/22464560[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894993/22464560%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894993/22464560)

Maybe this useful in your case