# How to insert multiple data using phpmysql form?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have three tables 
1. User database with username & home_team
2. User points with point_scored & user_name with match_no
3. User performance with total_points, user_name, match_played_count, home_team_wins_count

I have 2500 numbers of user in database.

First I post match_no & winning team through form and in code section I used below code, it works but after updating 400-500 records query stop working. I cant find solution? I check its flow but its proper. My postcode is like :

```
<?php
    require("../includes/commonClass.php");

    $classObj = new commonclass;

    $postedData = $classObj->getRequestedData();

    $setsession = $classObj->validsessionmanager();

    if(isset($_POST['submitht']))
    {
        $mid = $postedData['match'];
        $winteam = $postedData['team1'];            

           $classObj->getUserTable();
           $condht="home_team='".$winteam."'";
           $resultht = $classObj->selectSql($condht);                   
           $rowht = $classObj->fetchData($resultht);
           foreach($rowht as $rowsht)
           {
               $username=$rowsht['user_name'];

               $playupuser2['home_team_win']=1;
               $playupuser2['total_points']=10;
               $playupuser2['match_played']=1;
               $classObj->getUSerPerformanceTable();
               $classObj->userPostedData = $playupuser2;        
               $cond1 = "user_name='".$username."'";
               $insert_query = $classObj->updateData1($cond1);

                $playupuser3['point_scored']=10;
                $playupuser3['ht_status']=1;
                $classObj->getUserPointTable();
                $classObj->userPostedData = $playupuser3;       
                $cond2 = "user_name='".$username."' AND match_no='".$mid."'";
                $insert_query = $classObj->updateData1($cond2);
           }         

                if($insert_query == "success")
                {
                    echo "<script> alert ('Home team Upadated Sucessfully'); </script>";                            
                    echo "<script>window.location='hometeamUpdate.php'</script>";       
                }
   }       
   else   
   {
       echo "<script> alert ('Error Occured ')</script>";
   }
?>
```

Its properly work for 100-200 records and show proper alerts after updating.
I used xampp for php/MySQL.

Comment: Can you please show your insert query?

Comment: $playupuser3[] is my array which get all posted values and insert into database using condition given by $cond

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` on each iteration: `if (!$query) {echo mysql_error();}` That will make it clear which ones fail and why.

Answer (score 0):

May be the execution time is over. You will edit this line

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```

to higher value in xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php.
Also look  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin)