# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

This here is the entire error

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   1.1589  287288  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   1.7114  452400  require_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\common.inc.php' ) ..\index.php:13
3   29.6652 3663096 include_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\database_interface.lib.php' ) ..\common.inc.php:827
4   30.4972 3757456 require_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php' ) ..\database_interface.lib.php:88
```

All I tried doing was to open mysql console and then I entered the incorrect password(I don't remember the correct one), now whenever I am clicking on phpmyadmin I am getting the same error, I even uninstalled and installed WAMP. Any help?
I read this post here [Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin) but he suggests to install XAMPP instead and I have a huge database which won't work on XAMPP due to the difference in extensions. I changed this in config-default.php

```
/**
 * maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
 *
 * @global integer $cfg['ExecTimeLimit']
 */
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 900;
```

to 900 from 30 still the error is the same, also I did the same in my php.ini file.
This is the content of the file which is showing the error i.e **line  8 of mysql.dbi.lib.php**

```
if (! defined('PHPMYADMIN')) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: did you restart Apache after changing the php.ini? Did you check `phpinfo()` to see WHICH .ini file(s) were being used? phpinfo will also tell you the currently-in-effect values as well.

Comment: @MarcB I did restart apache, I even reinstalled WAMP.

Comment: Is the deeper issue here not  that the database server is not responding?

Comment: Why not concentrate on that then, instead of the execution time limit?

Comment: The thing is that I am unable to access anything in the DB, since I have reinstalled wamp therefore there is no user for the DB and I have lost my mind here seriously, its all blank

Comment: If you reinstalled WAMP that may have reinstalled mysql's own database where it keeps passwords. In that case the userid is `root` and the password is `blank` i.e. leave it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way of over coming this problem(according to me) is to reinstall WAMP, as RiggsFolly said this will reinstall the database of mysql but one more thing is needed here and that is removing phpmyadmin and then reinstalling it because due to some reason if this is not done, the time out error is persistent.