# cannot export datas to excel spreadsheets (file_get_contents(http://localhost:8000/css/print.css)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

First, I got the maximum execution time problem. But then i follow steps from this discussion [Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin). I set the `max_execution_time = 1000;` and `max_input_time = 1000 ;`.

And I also tried another answers, however, I got a new problem

```
"file_get_contents(http://localhost:8000/css/print.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"
```

I just tested with 3 or 4 records data to export to excel. It all works well when tested on the laptop of my friends.

**My laptop**

- processor:Intel(R) Celeron(R)
- CPU 1007U @1.5GHz 1.50GHz with
- RAM 4GB 64 bit.

I use Laravel framework and php for the codes. What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is that you've given absolutely no indication whatsoever of how you're trying to export to Excel, or what file_get_contents() has to do with that

Comment: yeah, i have solved it. The problem is i run with localhost:8000. when i just call with the folder name with activating xampp, it works well