# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1610

Tags: wordpress

I am facing that error while installing Jet pack plugin on my WordPress localhost site. i have search on this site many answer but that not fulfill my requirement

Comment: Something gets stuck when you run the installation script. Disable all plugins before installing Jetpack. If that doesn't help, try [increasing the maximum execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin).

Comment: @Hexaholic i have disable all my plugin but again that same error occurred

Answer (score 61):

Please

1. locate the file `[XAMPP Installation Directory]\php\php.ini` **(e.g. `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`)**
2. open `php.ini` in Notepad or any Text editor
3. locate the line containing **`max_execution_time`** and
4. increase the value from 30 to some larger number (e.g. set: `max_execution_time = 90`)
5. then restart Apache web server from the XAMPP control panel

If there will still be the same error after that, try to increase the value for the `max_execution_time` further more.

Comment: it doesn't work by the way the Error was atal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1610

Comment: Thanks a lot @Raphael .God bless you.

Answer (score 56):

@Raphael your solution does work. I encountered the same problem and solved it by increasing the maximum execution time to 180. There is an easier way to do it though:

1. Open the Xampp control panel
2. Click on 'config' behind 'Apache'
3. Select 'PHP (php.ini)' from the dropdown -> A file should now open in your text editor
4. Press ctrl+f and search for 'max_execution_time', you should fine a
   line which only says

   max_execution_time=30
5. Change 30 to a bigger number (180 worked for me), like this:

   max_execution_time=180
6. Save the file
7. 'Stop' Apache server
8. Close Xampp
9. Restart Xampp
10. 'Start' Apache server
11. Update Wordpress from the Admin dashboard
12. Enjoy ;)

Comment: Steps to follow, straight forward, somebody get this man/woman a drink!

Comment: I was doing this for local development, running on IIS.
I found my php.ini file in C://php (where I installed PHP). Then I restarted IIS.

Comment: well explained dude :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue to update `.htaccess` file inside your workspace (like `C:\xampp\htdocs\Nayan\.htaccess` in my case).

> Just update or add this `php_value max_execution_time 300` line before `# END WordPress`. Then save the file and try to install again.

If the error occurs again, you can maximize the value from `300` to `600`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply testing a local dev version of WordPress as I was an hitting timeouts when WordPress tries to update itself you can always disable updates for your local version like so: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-in-wordpress/

**Don't do this for a production site!**

Answer (score 0):

1. Find file:

   ```
   [XAMPP Installation Directory]\php\php.ini
   ```
2. open `php.ini`.
3. Find `max_execution_time` and increase the value of it as you required
4. Restart XAMPP control panel

Answer (score 0):

If you want modify the limit for a single script, you may try to change that limit at runtime:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```