# update failed during plugin installation of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation

I'm trying to install a woocommerce plugin on my wordpress website(locally) it is giving such error 'update failed' as you can see in picture,

how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please check the plugin & upgrade folder permission

Comment: with most of the plugins I want to install there is the same problem,it's not the case with only this one

Comment: We are faced this types of issue in last month. The reason is file permission. So change the file permission of plugins & upgrade folder. Once after update the plugin revert back the permission.

Comment: how do I change file permission of plugins, and then how to revert back?

Comment: Set the  wp-content/upgrade & wp-content/plugin folder permission 777 (Recursive). then revert back 775

Comment: how to revert back to 775 ??

Comment: chmod -775 wp-content/plugin 
chmod -775 wp-content/upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `wp-content/upgrade` directory and change folder permission to **777 (chmod)** or in windows make sure that the read only box is uncheck.

That only means you allow that directory to read write and execute without any restrictions.

Comment: I upgrade folder permission to 777 and uncheck the read only box as well,now when I want to search for plugins it show this error  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\ocover\wordpress-4.9.8\wordpress\wp-includes\Requests\Transport\cURL.php on line 463

Comment: Looks like the solution works. To fix the other problem just go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198287/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-c-xampp-htdocs-wo

Comment: Waoo !! I did the same thing earlier but didn't restart the apache , it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this error by increasing the execution time.
Just go to your Xampp Control Panel, Stop Apache server, click on config (Apache), then select PHP(php.ini) option, Press Ctrl+F type "execution" and hit enter, then just increase the size of execution time from 30 to 300, save the file and then start Apache again.
It Works for Me!

Answer (score 0):

see sometimes there is compatibility problem of site effects. If you can not fix, you can install another similar plugin

or

install a plugin that stop the updates of plugins ot theme according to what you want, to stop only the update of this specific plugin, like

https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-specific-plugin-updates/

after when you fixed or come new version you restart the update procedure

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that works for the installation of plugin is to upload the plugin via cPanel's File Manager or the FTP client (e.g FileZilla).

Download the WooCommerce Plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/. This will download a zipped file which can be uploaded onto the server.

After download, navigate your way to the `wp-content/plugins` folder on the cPanel. Upload the downloaded file, and extract the file to folder.

**NOTE:** remember to remove the version number from the name of the plugin after downloading e.g change woocommerce.4.0.1.zip to woocommerce.zip

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the files might have been corrupted during the update.

You’d need to access your site FILES, so that you can delete the WooCommerce plugin folder.
Locate the plugins folder, and remove the woocommerce folder from there. Once deleted, you should be able to go back to your site’s Dashboard and install the plugin again.

Answer (score -1):

If you install any plugins/themes, this could be the reason for continuously fails. Add the below line of code in ***wp-config.php***

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot how your wp-config.php file looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Download .zip From wordpress org/plugins/woocommerce/