# PHP Script Loading Forever

Tags: php, loops, cookies, infinite

**This is not a duplicate of [Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin); this has nothing to do with phpmyadmin.**

On my site, there is a form which sends POST data to a PHP script and loads a new page. When you submit the form, the page loads forever and then results in:

> The XXX.XXX page isn’t working XXX.XXX is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I thought it may be a traffic issue so I upgraded my hosting SSD and made the website only available to me to test it, but the problem still persisted. Here is my script:

```
<?php

$used_file  = 'used.txt';
$codes_file = 'codes.txt';

# Generates a random unused code from the code file 
function genCode() {
    global $used_file, $codes_file;
    $codes = file_get_contents($codes_file);
    $codes = explode("\n", $codes);
    $used  = file_get_contents($used_file);
    $used  = explode("\n", $used);
    foreach($codes as $code) {
        if(!in_array($code, $used))
            return $code;
    }
}

# Generate error string from error code
function getError($err) {
    switch($err) {
        case 1: return 'No submit';
        case 2: return 'Wrong password';
        case 3: return 'No password';
    }
}

# Adds generated code to the 'used' codes file
function append_used($code) {
    global $used_file, $codes_file;
    $str = $code . '\n';
    file_put_contents($used_file, $str, FILE_APPEND);
}

# Get user's IP (for cookie handling)
function getIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip;
}

# Cookie handling
# Set a cookie for how many times the form has been submitted by user

$used = 0;

if(isset($_COOKIE['used_twice'])) {
    $used = 3;
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['used_once']) && !isset($_COOKIE['used_twice'])) {
    setcookie('used_twice', getIP(), time()+18000);
    $used = 2;
}

if(!isset($_COOKIE['used_once'])) {
    setcookie('used_once', getIP());
    $used = 1;
}

# Check if all the POST data is correct

$password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
$submit   = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($password)) {

    if($password == 'test123') {

        if(isset($submit)) {

            $code = genCode();

        }

        else
            $err = 1;

    } else 
          $err = 2;

} else
    $err = 3;



# Now generate the new page
include 'web_functions.php';
getHead('Generated', 'Generated code');
getBody('Generated code');

?>



            <a href="../"><img src="goback.png"></img></a>
            <h2>Code Generated</h2>
            <br/>

            <?php
            if(!isset($err) && isset($thecode) && $used == 1) {
            ?>
            <center>
                <div class="bs-component">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
                <p>Your code is: </p> <strong> <?php echo $thecode; append_used($thecode); ?> </strong>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </center>
            <?php
            } elseif(isset($err)) {
            ?>
            <center>
            <div class="bs-component">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
            <p>There was an error:</p> <strong><?php echo getError($err); ?></strong>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </center>
            <?php
                } elseif(!isset($err) && $used != 1){
                ?>
                <center>
                <div class="bs-component">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
                <p>You can only use the code generator once every 5 hours. Please try again later.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </center>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="bs-component">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
                <p>There was an unexpected error. Please try again.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>


                <?php closeTags();
                getFooter(); ?>
      </div>


 </div>


 </div>
</div>
```

What could be causing this issue?

**Edit:** The error log says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded on line 13
```

Line 13 is within the foreach loop.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: And how large are those files?

Comment: My guess is something in web_functions.php as there is nothing obvious here You should however find some info in your error log.

Comment: Btw...  The img-tag in HTML is a self closing tag, you don't write `<img ...></img>`, you write `<img ... />`

Comment: Tbh it looks like you should be using a database to store your codes. If you have 1,000,000 codes, every time one is taken it's going to take longer and longer. Imagine doing 999,999 iterations to take the last element...

Comment: 1. I've updated the post with the error_log. 2. 4.09KB 3. Thanks, I have no idea why I did that. 4. That could be it, there are about 34,000 in there.

Comment: we need the code where `genCode()` is called