# Query execution was interrupted (max_statement_time exceeded)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have run a query direct in phpmyadmin only 5 sec time taken but when load in php query than i face this error Query execution was interrupted

> max_statement_time exceeded

Comment: have you checked SET SESSION MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=10;

Answer (score 0):

i check the phpmyadmin and have a wrapper inside Util.php `...function .....@set_time_limit((int) $GLOBALS['cfg']['ExecTimeLimit']); ...` and lead to config.values.php `'ExecTimeLimit' => 'validateNonNegativeNumber',`  or just in case to config.inc.php  ( could be like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858161/5781320 ) : in my case isn't a value set you may check if in your case is!
if you do not find anything you should check php.ini "Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini "  -> https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: but these settings can only change in server administrator and administrator set this value maximum 300 seconds. what can i do now??

Comment: @Anees ulmujtaba if you have no access to these you can only contact the administrator.