# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded when importing a database to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using Mampp and already updated `php.ini` files of Mampp server and PHP versions I have installed on my computer (Mac). Tried with:

```
max_execution_time = 0;
```

or giving a high amount of time:

```
max_execution_time = 3000000;
```

And restarted Apache. I also changed `config.default.php` file from Xampp, and updated this line:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

The database file is 300Mb size (also tried with the .zip file which is 30Mb), and when I try to upload to phpmyadmin and I keep getting the same error:

> Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Lexer.php
> on line 921

Comment: Please clarify what format of data you're importing. Have you looked at the data file itself and it's logical / correct?

Comment: I think this can help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin . Don't forget to restart the local server after you change the server configuration files

Comment: thats strange, i've imported way more bigger db file with default settings-- have you tried to modify max post size?