# how to fix this xampp phpmyadmin timeout limit error

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to import a large sql file to localhost phpmyadmin, but getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\UtfString.php on line 232".
```

I am using XAMPP latest version.

I have already increased the max execution and upload limit, and also modified `config.default.php` file variable `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0` but I am still facing the same error.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAUM8.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin?rq=2  you can find this here