# xampp Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin when trying to import a large file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

see this problem when trying to import a large file to the database:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

I have tried all the solutions on the internet but the same problem

I also used the solutions here and it didn't work: [Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin)

mysql in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Don't put files in database. Save them on server and only persist relative path to file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit phpmyadmin.conf!

Sample path: C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf

Or edit through your WAMP icon by: ->Apache -> Alias directories -> phpMyAdmin

you will find the code as below :

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/apps/phpmyadmin5.2.1/">
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Require local
    # To import big file you can increase values
      php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 1028M
      php_admin_value post_max_size 1028M
      php_admin_value max_execution_time 3600
      php_admin_value max_input_time 3600
    </Directory>
```

change the variable :  `php_admin_value max_execution_time` as you need

Comment: I use XAMPP and can't find this file

Comment: Check this path : 

C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php 

and set this variable to zero as below

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;