# MySQL: Resolving 'Maximum Execution Time of 300 Seconds Exceeded' Error

Tags: phpmyadmin

When attempting to upload a 150MB file to MySQL using XAMPP, I consistently encounter a

> 'Fatal error: 300 seconds exceeded'

message, despite configuring `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` in 'config.default.php' and adjusting 'php.ini' settings such as post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, max_input_time, and memory_limit.
What further steps can I take to resolve this issue and successfully upload large files to MySQL?"

Comment: Try to change *xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php* as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628333/5563083) answer.

Comment: You seem to be using phpmyadmin for uploading large files. Phpmyadmin being a web application is not really suitable for this task. I would use mysql load data infile functionality from a command line or proper desktop GUI.